# How do I view stored procedure text using MySQL?

Tags: mysql

I can't view the text of a stored procedure in a schema called master_db.

This returns NULL in the "Create Procedure" column:

```
show create procedure my_proc_name;
```

This shows procedure text for all schemas except master_db where it is always NULL:

```
select ROUTINE_SCHEMA, ROUTINE_NAME, ROUTINE_TYPE, ROUTINE_DEFINITION 
from INFORMATION_SCHEMA.ROUTINES;
```

I have `GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON master_db.*` ...

I have `SELECT` access to the mysql.proc table.

How can I view the text of my_proc_name?

Comment: what is master_db in mysql?

Comment: show create procedure returns other fields. It returns NULL for `Create Procedure`. The documentation says this would happen if I didn't have rights to use the procedure but I presume GRANT ALL includes such rights.

Comment: @Anil - Not sure if master_db is special in some way, possibly just a schema name.

Comment: I think your procedure master_db is created by another user `DEFINER`, try use `DEFINER` or `root` user to execute `show create procedure ...`, you can recreate the procedure use current user account, then you can view it body. [see this link](http://stackoverflow.com/a/16602169/1484621)

Comment: @Yu Jiaao - your explanation is correct (despite the proc's security type being 'INVOKER'). Thank you.